# What is the best implementation of a recursive struct?

Tags: rust

I want to implement a `Treep` by rust. The node struct of `Treep` is

```
#[derive(Clone)]
struct TreepNode {
    data: i32,
    left: Option<Box<TreepNode>>,
    right: Option<Box<TreepNode>>,
}
```

Then I define a function to implement the right rotate operation.

```
fn rightRotate(&self) -> Box<TreepNode> {
    match self.clone().left {
        None => return Box::new(self.clone()),
        Some(ref mut leftTree) => {
            let mut selfTree = self.clone();
            selfTree.left = leftTree.right.clone();
            leftTree.right = Some(Box::new(selfTree));
            return leftTree.clone()
        }
    }
}
```

This code can be compiled. However, the code is ugly because there are lot of `clone()` and `Some` in it. Is there any better way to optimize the code?

Comment: are you sure this code does what you expect? I'd assume that the `rightRotate` function should modify the `TreepNode`

Comment: Yes, I am sure that this code is correct. The question is how to avoid to use clone() in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid `clone()` if you consume `Self`:

```
fn right_rotate(mut self) -> Box<TreepNode> {
    match self.left.take() {
        None => Box::new(self),
        Some(mut left) => {
            self.left = left.right.take();
            left.right = Some(Box::new(self)); 
            left
        }
    }
}
```